# VBA IE automation through Excel - cannot figure out how to manipulate a Java link/element

Tags: java, excel, vba, automation

I've been teaching myself VBA recently to try and build a code that would eventually log in to a website to upload data from an Excel spreadsheet.

The code will at this point log in to the site and move through most of the pages until after a search screen. What occurs is I have the code take a unique ID number to pull up an individual. On the next screen after the search is performed, the site provides a list (which is just one individual due to the ID number being used). I need to be able to "click" the name of the individual to be able to proceed, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I can't provide the actual site and any real identifiers of my code, but I will post what I can in hopes someone can assist.

Here is the HTML (an excerpt), the table I need to be able to click is pretty much any value in this block.

```
    <tr>
<td><input type='hidden' id='grdProfile' name='grdProfile'        value="" /><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'      id='grdProfile_main' style="overflow:hidden;table-     layout:fixed;position:relative;width:100%;" class="ig_2e49b359_r0 MT"     onresize="igtbl_onResize('grdProfile');" onmousemove="igtbl_tableMouseMove    (event,'grdProfile');" onmouseup="igtbl_tableMouseUp   (event,'grdProfile');"><tr><td align="left"   style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;">
<div id='grdProfile_hdiv' onscroll="igtbl_onStationaryMarginScroll(event, 'grdProfile', 'grdProfile_hdiv')" style='overflow:hidden;width:100%;position:relative;'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='position:relative;table-layout:fixed;height:100%;width: 978px;' ' bandNo='0'>thead onmousedown='igtbl_headerClickDown(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseup='igtbl_headerClickUp(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseout='igtbl_headerMouseOut(event,"grdProfile");' onmousemove='igtbl_headerMouseMove(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseover='igtbl_headerMouseOver(event,"grdProfile");' oncontextmenu='igtbl_headerContextMenu(event,"grdProfile");' ondblclick='igtbl_cellDblClick(event,"grdProfile");'>
<tr><th id='grdProfile_c_0_0' columnNo='0' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_1' columnNo='1' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_2' columnNo='2' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">Last Name</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_3' columnNo='3' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">First Name</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_4' columnNo='4' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">Middle Initial/Name</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_5' columnNo='5' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">AgentID</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_6' columnNo='6' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">SSN</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_7' columnNo='7' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">Profile Key</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_8' columnNo='8' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">CRD Number</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_9' columnNo='9' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">NPN</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_10' columnNo='10' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">UNID</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_11' columnNo='11' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">OFFICE_NBR</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_12' columnNo='12' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">DEPT_NBR</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_13' columnNo='13' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">FollowupId</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_14' columnNo='14' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">STATUS</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_15' columnNo='15' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">REGION</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_16' columnNo='16' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">RowState</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_17' columnNo='17' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">View</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_18' columnNo='18' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">Login Id</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_19' columnNo='19' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">Rep Id</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_20' columnNo='20' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">Special Handling Required?</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_21' columnNo='21' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">Special Handling Notes</th></tr>
</thead></table></div></td></tr>
<tr id="grdProfile_mr" style=""><td id="grdProfile_mc" align='left' style="width:100%;vertical-align:top;">
<div id="grdProfile_div" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;width:100%;" onscroll='igtbl_onScroll(event,"grdProfile");' tabIndexPage='0' hideFocus='true'>
<table id='G_grdProfile' bandNo='0'  border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='table-layout:fixed;width:978px;position:relative;' onSelectStart='igtbl_selectStart(event,"grdProfile");' onmousedown='igtbl_cellClickDown(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseup='igtbl_cellClickUp(event,"grdProfile");' oncontextmenu='igtbl_cellContextMenu(event,"grdProfile");' onmousemove='igtbl_cellMouseMove(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseover='igtbl_cellMouseOver(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseout='igtbl_cellMouseOut(event,"grdProfile");' ondblclick='igtbl_cellDblClick(event,"grdProfile");'>
<colgroup><col width='20px' /><col width='145px' /><col width='143px' /><col width='100px' /><col width='100px' />
<col width='90px' /><col width='100px' /><col width='100px' /><col width='180px' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' />
<col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' />
<col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' />
<col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /><col width='1px' style='display:none;' /></colgroup>
<thead style='display:none;' onmousedown='igtbl_headerClickDown(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseup='igtbl_headerClickUp(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseout='igtbl_headerMouseOut(event,"grdProfile");' onmousemove='igtbl_headerMouseMove(event,"grdProfile");' onmouseover='igtbl_headerMouseOver(event,"grdProfile");' oncontextmenu='igtbl_headerContextMenu(event,"grdProfile");'>
<tr><th id='grdProfile_c_0_0' columnNo='0' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_1' columnNo='1' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_2' columnNo='2' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_3' columnNo='3' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_4' columnNo='4' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_5' columnNo='5' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_6' columnNo='6' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_7' columnNo='7' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_8' columnNo='8' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_9' columnNo='9' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_10' columnNo='10' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_11' columnNo='11' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_12' columnNo='12' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_13' columnNo='13' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_14' columnNo='14' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_15' columnNo='15' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_16' columnNo='16' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_17' columnNo='17' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH ">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_18' columnNo='18' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_19' columnNo='19' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_20' columnNo='20' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
<th id='grdProfile_c_0_21' columnNo='21' height='20px' class="ig_2e49b359_r1 ig_2e49b359_r4 GRSHand ig_2e49b359_rh04 GH " style="display:none;">&nbsp;</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody style="height:100%">
<tr id='grdProfile_r_0' style='height:20px;' DataKey='XXXXX3658'><td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr><span id='fup_agentstdsearch_***ID***'>0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td iDV="False" class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr><input type='checkbox' onpropertychange='igtbl_chkBoxChange(event,"grdProfile");' tabindex='-1' /></nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***Last***</nobr></td><td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***First***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***Middle***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>***ID***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***ID4***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***ID2***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr>***ID3***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>***ID2***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>***Center ID***</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>PROD</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>0</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>7040</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand"><nobr><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="viewProfile('***ID***','***Last*** ***First***');">View Profile Summary</a></nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td>
<td class="ig_2e49b359_r1 GRSHand" style="display:none;"><nobr>&nbsp;</nobr></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></table></td>
```

Here is the code I have to reference what I believe needs to be clicked, but I'm assuming an event or script need to run.

```
     With IE
 While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 .Document.frames("mainParent").Document.forms("AgentProfileList").Document.getElementById("grdProfile_r_0").Document.getElementById("grdProfile_rc_0_2").Click
 End With
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Public Function CallJavascript(ie As InternetExplorer, codeToExecute As String)
  Dim DOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim w As Object
  Set DOC = ie.Document
  Set w = DOC.parentWindow
  CallJavascript = w.eval(codeToExecute)
End Function
```

You would be looking to call `ViewProfile`... probably with `CallJavascript("ViewProfile('ID','Last First');")`, but you may need to play around with it.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12k71sw7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm working to fix how the HTML shows, sorry about how bad it is...

Comment: View Profile is one I don't need. It only links to the grdProfile #17 box. I believe the one I need is something like this <span id='fup_agentstdsearch_***Variable ID#***'>. If I pull up the code via F12, and use the work as HTML option, there is a javascript listed similar to that name. Even if I get it to work, I'm concerned about the variable data (ID and name), as I would like it to work automatically each time a new person is entered. Is that possible, or could I use innerText somehow to accomplish that?

Comment: When you call the function, you can pass it whatever code you want. If the value needs to be variable, do something like `CallJavascript("fup_agentstdsearch('" & variableID & "');")`. Unfortunately, without seeing the page's code, it's much more difficult to identify what function is doing the work.

Comment: <SPAN id=fup_agentstdsearch_3765545><A onclick='javascript:xfupshow("fup_agentstdsearch_3765545");' href="javascript:void(0);">                This is the code that appears to be what will go to the next area. There is also an event named grpProfile that appears many times, but I believe it would have to be fired in reference to element IDs grdProfile_r_0 and/or grdProfile_rc_0_2 as it will shows up if more than one person is listed. One of the ways it is listed is onmousedown='igtbl_headerClickDown(event,"grdProfile");   ----I wish this site was public, it would be much easier to explain...

Comment: I've tried this in an attempt to fire the event, but it doesn't do anything except throw a 438 error.

Comment: `With ie
 While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
 Set objLink = .Document.frames("mainParent").Document.forms("AgentProfileList").Document.getElementById("grdProfile_r_0").Document.getElementById("grdProfile_rc_0_2")
 objLink.dispatchEvent ("grdProfile")
 End With`

Comment: Try `CallJavascript(ie, "xfupshow(""fup_agenstdsearch_3765545"");")`

Comment: Thank you C. White. The more I looked into the website using the Developer tools with Chrome, I found out there is a different event that needs to be activated. I have a more relevant question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892918/dispatchevent-vba-ie-automation)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trail and error and internet research I figured out I needed to fire certain onmouse events on a cell in the Java table.

I documented what I did on the linked thread at [link][dispatchEvent - VBA IE automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892918/dispatchevent-vba-ie-automation?lq=1)