# Clicking on a javascript <span> element with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba

This is on a private website so I cannot paste the entire code or link.
I know the span # is 41 but I cannot click Export to CSV.

```html
<SPAN onclick="function onclick(event) { ur_Button_click(event); }" class=urBtnRow>
<A onclick=ur_Button_click(event); tabIndex=0 id=BUTTON_TOOLBAR_2_btn3_acButton title="Export to CSV" class=urBtnStd onkeydown=ur_Button_keypress(event); style="OVERFLOW: visible; TEXT-ALIGN: center" href="javascript:void(0);" ct="B" ocl="sapbi_page.sendCommandArray([['GUID','8',0],['NOUILOCK','X',0],['BI_COMMAND_TYPE','ABSTRACT',0]],event);" ti="0" st="">Export to CSV</A></SPAN>
```

When I run the below code in VBA the Message box will come up and say Export to CSV but no matter what I try I cannot click on it!

I am a newbie when it comes to this.

```
With ie
    For i5 = 0 To .document.frames(0).document.all.tags("SPAN").Length - 1
        With .document.frames(0).document.all.tags("SPAN").Item(i5)
            If InStr(.innerText, "Export to CSV") > 0 Then
                MsgBox .innerText, vbInformation
```

I have tried:

```
.Click
.onclick = "function onclick(event) { ur_Button_click(event); }"
.onclick
.Parentelement.click
.Fireevent ("onclick")
.focus.click
.execScript (onclick)
```

The i5 value is 41 and it will always be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dispatchEvent - VBA IE automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892918/dispatchevent-vba-ie-automation)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how the site runs.  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41769834/edit) to clarify --- are you trying to use VBA to trigger the JavaScript `click` event associated with your `<a>` element?  Please also add the code that creates the `ie` object --- there are several different flavors of VBA IE control, as I recall.